# mpdf só exibe no firerox

Tags: php, css, mpdf

Estou usando o mPDF e ele só está gerando os relatórios corretamente no FireFox ou abrindo pelo IE. Se tento abrir o arquivo com leitor de PDF ele retorna o erro de falha ao carregar documento PDF.

```
<?php 
 include("../crud/_views/plugins/mpdf60/mpdf.php");

 $html = "
teste
 ";



$mpdf = new mPDF('','', '', '', 55, 18, 19, 15, 0, 0, '');
$css = file_get_contents('../crud/_views/plugins/mpdf60/estilo.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output('');
```

Pelo código eu notei que o erro é gerado na linha `$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);`, se eu removo ela o PDF é exibido normalmente, porém não fica com o estilo css.

Arquivo estilo.css

```
    .titulo{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Times, "Times New Roman";
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sub-titulo{
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Times, "Times New Roman";
 font-weight: bold;
}
.numero{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.direita{
 text-align: right;
}

.center{
 text-align: center;
}

.alinhamento{
 margin-right: : 10%;
}

.direita{
 text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do MPF e qual o conteudo de $css e $html?

Comment: A última versão do MPDF, o conteúdo está no código, o $css é apenas a referencia do link, conforme documentação do mpdf https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html

Comment: Ultima versão qual? O mpdf tem em mais de um site pra baixar, as pessoas pensam estar pegando no site oficial quando na verdade não estão e pensam ser a "ultima versão" quando não é. Informa a versão exata. E por favor, eu já pedi, informa o conteudo de `$html`.

Comment: Já solucionei com a resposta abaixo, obrigado!

Comment: Rafael se resolveu com a resposta abaixo, que não tem lógica com a explicação da doc isso indica que tem algum problema na versão que você esta usando e por isto é importante informar este tipo de detalhe. Claramente a resposta é apenas uma solução paliativa e não explica o porque do ocorrido.

Comment: Tudo bem, a versão é a 6.0 retirada do site http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php e usando como referência seu manual. Editei a pergunta com o conteúdo completo da página q gera o pdf

Comment: Como eu disse, 6.0 não é a ultima versão, e até aonde eu sei o site que distribui oficialmente o MPDF é o proprio repositório do github deles: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases ou via composer (somente versão 6.1 e 7 do mpdf). Editei a minha resposta e restaurei ela.

Comment: Rafael, logo que entrei no site mpdf1 já vi as seguintes mensagens: Updated 16/03/2016 - This mPDF website is now closed down. Ou seja esse site esta inativo, diferente do github cujo o autor do mpdf continua mantendo os updates e correções. Adicionei ao corpo da resposta. Obs: Quando o teu HTML não tem a tag <HEAD> então é necessário o uso do segundo parametro com o valor `2`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com todos detalhamentos, você pode até imaginar que estou pegando no seu pé de maldade ou implicância, mas não é isso. O motivo é que você recebeu uma boa resposta do Samuel, mas eu percebi o problema que pode ser mais grave, você esta usando uma versão desatualizada da qual pode conter BUGs e isto lhe causaria problemas, então por isto insisto na resposta e comentários que lhe mandei, pois as vezes as coisas são mais complexas e meu intuito é te ajudar mostrando aonde esta o problema grave de usar uma ferramenta que possa conter BUGS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está tentando gerar um PDF colocando um código em .css nele, por isso o erro.

Tente referenciar o css dentro do seu html, e retirar a linha `$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);`.

Para referenciar o css dentro de seu html, é só colocar a seguinte linha:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[CAMINHO_DO_ARQUIVO_CSS]">`

Comment: Deu certo assim, só não entendi porque não funcionou conforme a referência do manual. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. E se puder, marca a resposta como correta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a versão que está usando do `mpdf` não é a ultima versão como você afirmou, pois a versão mais atualizada do MPDF tem namespace:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

Ou:

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new Mpdf();
```

---

Não quer dizer que você não possa usar as versões 5 e 6 do MPDF, só estou comentando isto porque você afirmou convictamente que estava usando a ultima, e pelo seu código creio não ser.

Você também afirmou estar usando a versão **6.0**, mas a versão mais atualizada dentro do "6" é o **6.1** e não o **6.0**, ou seja podem haver BUGs na versão que baixou.

A instalação oficial do MPDF 5.7, 6.1 e 7 (o 7 ainda em beta) são feitas via `composer` e https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases (versão 6 ou inferiores), se você não instalou via `composer` ou não baixo do repositório oficial então provavelmente baixou uma versão **não oficial** ou de site de terceiros do MPDF, logo pode ser uma versão com BUGs e logo você esta se arriscando.

> **Nota:** Você baixou do site http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php e o próprio site tem duas notas dizendo:
>
> - Updated 16/03/2016
> - This mPDF website is now closed down.
>
> Ou seja, essas versões que você baixou não tem update a um ano e esse site não receberá mais atualizações e esta "inativado", ou seja provavelmente ele não irá mais atualizar, somente via github agora ou composer.

Se estiver usando PHP 5.6 ou superior pode preferencialmente instalar a versão mais recente usando composer:

```
 composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

Para instalar a versão 6.1 manualmente baixe:

- https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases/tag/v6.1.0

Um detalhe importante acaso a falha ainda continue, conforme o manual oficial:

- https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html

O uso do `WriteHtml` estava assim:

```
<?php

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
```

Ou seja, se vai injetar o CSS diretamente então o `WriteHTML` talvez tenha que usar o modo `2` se o HTML **não contiver a tag HEAD**, se contiver pelo que entendi não é necessário.

Comment: Segui todos os passos, atualizei a versão. Inclusive peguei a versão de instalar manualmente em meu localhost. Peguei o exemplo do próprio mpdf para css e deu o mesmo erro. No firefox abriu, quando salva em pdf ele não abre o arquivo.

Comment: @RafaelMeirim agora você já mudou o problema, primeiro você fala não abre no chrome, agora você fala, "quando salva", são duas coisas totalmente diferentes. Como você esta salvando esse PDF? Usando headers ou com a função do próprio MPDF?

Comment: O erro da no chrome e quando salva o arquivo ele salva normalmente, porém ao abrir o pdf ele não lê com o leitor padrão, apenas no firefox, como se fosse um arquivo corrompido.

Comment: @RafaelMeirim TÁ, mas como você esta salvando? Com headers ou com a função do proprio MPDF. Poh cara de novo isso, na outra pergunta foi a mesma coisa, eu te peço algo, vc só responde metade ou responde algo vago demais, por favor amigo se concentra em ler o que é pedido, e tenta em apenas um comentário responder a tudo se fazer os outros terem que ficar pedindo 2 ou 3 vezes a mesma coisa. Então por favor, explica como você esta fazendo o download. Obrigado

Comment: Testei salvando diretamente o arquivo ou exibindo o mesmo. O problema que não é erro das minhas funções em si, pois testei com o arquivo fonte do próprio mpdf sem alterar nada e da o mesmo erro. Por exemplo usando essa função padrão require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyleA4.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();

exit;

Comment: @RafaelMeirim eu não sei o que é "salvar diretamente", você apertou Ctrl+S ou clicou em um botão no navegador chamado salvar? Pode explicar isso direito? Entenda uma coisa, uma palavra pode ser muito ambigua, por isso deve se explicar de maneira técnica o que EXATAMENTE você fez, tipo "eu fui e X e então abriu uma janela ae eu cliquei em Y e ocorreu o download", isso é uma explicação técnica e util, se dizer algo como "salvei diretamente" não dá pra entender.